# When is it necessary to add a "width: 100%;" to your website?

Tags: html, css, width

I'm just sitting here working on a small website, and I noticed adding width:100% makes a scroll bar and you can go over just a slight bit. That really irritates me. So when is it necessary to add it?

Comment: You can use `margin: 0` to get rid of your scroll bar issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The width:100% value makes the div or page literally 100% wide.
This means that if you have any margin, padding, or other elements next to the 100% wide element there will be a scrollbar.

So to avoid this make sure there is no padding or width.

And when the width:100% is necessary to use is a difficult question to answer, it depends entirely on the designer and project.

Nothing forces you to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use width 100% in mostly cases. Becasue when you use div it's by default display: block; and its fit automatically 100%, if you not need float property.